# Google oauth satellizer 404 Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, satellizer

This is my code. I am using `authenticate('google')`. After clicking on allow button I get **error 404**. 
I am using **satellizer.js** for google authentication.

Please help me if you understand this error.

> Error in browser
>   POST http://localhost:8080/auth/google 404 (Not Found)

```
Object {data: "Cannot POST /auth/google↵", status: 404, config: Object, statusText: "Not Found"}
```

> Inside controller

```
 $scope.authenticate = function (provider) {
            $auth.link(provider)
                .then(function(response) {
                    // You have successfully linked an account.
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function(response) {
                    // Handle errors here.
                    console.log('----------error--------')
                    console.log(response);
                });
        };
```

> My code inside app.js

```
$authProvider.google({
            clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxx2op4madn.apps.googleusercontent.com'
        });

        $authProvider.google({
            url: '/auth/google',
            authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            redirectUri: window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
            requiredUrlParams: ['scope'],
            optionalUrlParams: ['display'],
            scope: ['profile', 'email'],
            scopePrefix: 'openid',
            scopeDelimiter: ' ',
            display: 'popup',
            type: '2.0',
            popupOptions: {width: 452, height: 633}
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue actually it's find a post request on that URL you can add some configuration inside you `server.js` file follow this given GIT-URL.

[github satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js)